# Regex to match all characters and new lines?

Tags: php, regex

Just ran into a bit of an issue with my regex. I would like to match all content inside the square bracket tags.

Here is my regex: `/(?:\[.*])(.*)(?:\[\/.*])/`

I am running it against this content:

```
[TITLE]More Things[/TITLE]
[BODY]This is not working
still not working
nope, hasn't magically started working

I'd like to match double carriage returns[/BODY]
```

It will only match the single line tags at the moment. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you have nested tags? Do you want to get nested tagged texts, too?

Comment: Nope, I will never be using nested tags with this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on php, you just need to add `s` modifier. And also it's better to capture the opening tag and refer it while writing pattern for the closing tag.

```
/(?:\[([^\]]*)\])(.*?)(?:\[\/\1\])/s
```

If you're on javascript then you must need to turn each `.` in the above regex to `[\S\s]`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tV6oG0/3)

Comment: I am using php, however when I use the s modifier, it offsets the results I think? Does it return different results?

Comment: I am doing `preg_match_all()` and it seems to only be returning one result.

Comment: I see the example is working, however when I run it using `preg_match_all()` it is returning 3 empty arrays. I will try figure out the issue.

Comment: use this https://regex101.com/r/tV6oG0/4 and get the tag name from index 1 and it's content from index 2.